# synaptics: No touchpad found

Tags: drivers, touchpad, synaptics

No touchpad found

> No touchpad was found in this system. If the system has a touchpad,
>   please make sure that the synaptics driver is properly installed and
>   configured.  If your touchpad is not found, though the driver is
>   installed and configured correctly, please compile detailed
>   information about your touchpad hardware and report this issue to the
>   issue tracker.

Touchpad not working on toshiba c650. I have ubuntu 12.04 installed. Right click works, nothing else.

Any Ideas about this? Guess I am looking for synaptics touchpad drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who may need it later:

Found the drivers. Synaptics TouchPad driver for X.Org server

Just go to the ubuntu software centre and type in synaptics. It should come up with many entries with the same title. Choose the one that has been evaluated by other members (the one with stars)